# How to Authenticate a user from a LDAP directory with his username and password?

Tags: java, ldap, spring-ldap

I am new to LDAP API. I am able to connect to a LDAP server and search the user. How would I authenticate a user with username/password using LDAP API? I don't see any authenticate method on `DirContext`.
To Authenticate a user Do I have to:

1. Pass user's password as SECURITY_CREDENTIALS
2. Make the LDAP connection
3. Search for the given username

Does this mean authentication in LDAP?

Comment: Is this LDAP server a windows domain controller?

Comment: Not sure as it is Client's AD. Does it matter?

Comment: I doubt if windows AD will be configured for simple authentication based on user/password. It would be mostly configured to talk NTLMv1 or NTLMv2 (since windows 2007) or SPNEGO, in corporate/production environments.

Comment: Let's say it is configured for authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a client connects to an LDAP directory server, the connection authorization state is set to `anonymous`. LDAP clients use the BIND request to change the authorization state of a connection. Each BIND request changes the connection authorization state to `anonymous`, and each successful BIND request changes the authorization state of the connection to the authorization state associated with the successful BIND request, that is, that of the user. Failed BIND requests leave the connection in an `anonymous` state.

The client constructs a `BindRequest` (either simple BIND request or a form of a SASL bind request) transmits to the LDAP directory server and interprets the response from the server, including any response controls that might accompany  the BIND response. A result code of zero in the BIND response indicates that the LDAP directory server matched the credentials and the user is authenticated.

If the distinguished name of the user is known, then a BIND request can be constructed from the distinguished name. If not known, the LDAP client must construct a search request, transmit it the server and interpret the response. The distinguished name is always included in a successful search response that returns at least one entry. Then use the distinguished returned in the search response to construct the BIND request as above.

In the simplest case:

```
// exception handling is not shown
final String dn = ....;
final byte[] password = ....;
final BindRequest bindRequest = new SimpleBindRequest(dn,password);
final LDAPConnection ldapConnection = new LDAPConnection(hostname,port);
final BindResult bindResult = ldapConnection.bind(bindRequest);
final ResultCode resultCode = bindResult.getResultCode();
if(resultCode.equals(ResultCode.SUCCESS))
{
    // user is authenticated
}
ldapConnection.close();
```

If you are using Java, you should use the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) (JNDI should not be used for new code).

#### see also

- [LDAP: Using Java to BIND](https://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/using-java-to-bind-to-a-directory-server/)
- [LDAP: Programming Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Comment: This may sound stupid as I am new to LDAP. Is user typed password different from LDAP server's SECURITY_CREDENTIALS to make the connection?

Comment: You'll hate this answer: it depends. One can also proxy authenticate which requires credentials of another user.

Answer (score 2):

You can try JAAS. There is [com.sun.security.auth.module.LdapLoginModule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/LdapLoginModule.html) in JDK for this purpose. I tried it and it works nice.

Comment: I understand this JAAS module and that is our future requirement. For POC purpose for now I have to come over this problem.

Comment: In that case you would need to use an LDAP API and do a "bind" which passes the login credential to LDAP and essentially gets back a true/false that the user authenticated.  After that you can query for the user's information.

Comment: @ChrisNava How would I pass username/password to bind a user? How would I connect to LDAP server? Through user entered password or some predefined password?

Comment: You can try `UnboundId LDAP SDK`. I tried it too it it works great. It is much siplier then JNDI and support some additional interesting features.

Comment: This would be dependent on the API you choose.  In general, you pass the userid and password through to a bind method (consider bind(user,password) to be what you would expect a login(user,password) method to do.)  Then you would do a search() (or some such) for the user's groups/roles and use that information for access control.  All of the above is very dependent on the API and the schema of the LDAP database.

Comment: @Himanshu : I also need to validate the user name and password to LDAp server after getting bind from Master user . but did not find any solution , did you have any solution how should i proceed